# Up-to-date Scala archetype for Maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, autocomplete, maven-archetype

I'm looking for a up-to-date archetype for developing Scala with Maven framework support. The newest one I could find is this one "https://github.com/davidB/scala-archetype-simple", which is 2 years old. The one that came bundled with IntelliJ preinstalled Maven is even older. I am able to program Scala with the default IBT framework but want to use a library that is exclusively deployed for Maven.

To be honest, I don't have much experience with Maven but I never had problems when using it in my Java projects. But when I use any of the named archetypes at first there is nothing working until I update the scala library. Then at least the importing of classes works. But IntelliJ still gives me all kinds of errors. It looks like the IDE gets confused between Java and Scala syntax for some reason. It gives me the option to autocomplete stuff like `List.$plus$plus[B,That](that...` but when I click on that, it is not recognized (`List.++(...`is not showing up at all).

Now I'm guessing this is because of a lot of outdated libraries loaded through the archetype (at least I hope). Is there a newer archetype out there or is my only option to update all the dependencies on my own?

It might also be my IntelliJ install on Linux, I'll try it on my windows PC as soon as I get to it.

---

**UPDATE**

Okay so I have managed to do it completely without an archetype. But the question still stands, is there an up-to-date archetype out there that doesn't use the 6 year old `maven-scala-plugin`, but rather the new `scala-maven-plugin`? And why is the only one I can find so old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official tutorial at https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html#creating-your-first-project mentions `net.alchim31.maven:scala-archetype-simple` which can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.alchim31.maven/scala-archetype-simple